Mutating reference type doesn't work with .animation(_:value:)
How can I animate changes to a view when the value being mutated is a reference type?

In the example below, changing the reminder time updates the order but without animation.

I thought arrays were value types, but maybe event.reminders is a reference, hence not triggering an update? If so I guess the .animation(_:value:) isn't the right approach?

What are the alternatives?
import SwiftUI

struct MissingAnimationWhenChangingArrayOrder: View {
    let event: Event
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(event.reminders.sorted { $0.dateTime < $1.dateTime }) { reminder in
            ReminderView(reminder: reminder)
        }
        .animation(.spring, value: event.reminders)
    }
}

#Preview {
    var event = Event(
        reminders: [
            Reminder(title: "Meeting 1", dateTime: .now),
            Reminder(title: "Meeting 2", dateTime: .now)
        ]
    )
    return MissingAnimationWhenChangingArrayOrder(event: event)
}

struct ReminderView: View {
    @Bindable var reminder: Reminder
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: $reminder.dateTime)
        .frame(width: 200)
    }
}

@Observable
class Event {
    var reminders: [Reminder]
    init(reminders: [Reminder]) {
        self.reminders = reminders
    }
}

@Observable
class Reminder: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var dateTime: Date
    init(title: String, dateTime: Date) {
        self.title = title
        self.dateTime = dateTime
    }

    static func == (lhs: Reminder, rhs: Reminder) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}


This is indeed because of reference type semantics.
The way the .animation modifier works, is that it checks whether its value: parameter has changed (as determined by ==) after a view update. SwiftUI stores an "old version" of value: before the a view update, then runs the view update by calling body, then compares the new value: it received during the body call with the "old value" it had. If they are unequal, start the animation.
This works fine for value types, but for reference types, the "old version" of value: is just another copy of the reference to the same object! When you change a property, the old version that SwiftUI stores "changes" to the same value as well because it is the same instance. So SwiftUI always finds that they are equal, unless you have implemented == in a very wrong way :)
Another contributing factor is that, you display a sorted array in ForEach, but you never actually sort the event.reminders array itself. If you had sorted it, then the equality  comparison would be unequal. Arrays are value types, after all, even though the old and new array contain references to the same two Reminder objects, the order is different.
Note that even if Reminder is a value type, your implementation of == will prevent the animation, because it only compares the IDs. Changing the dates of the reminders will not cause the reminders to be unequal.
To fix this, I would map the array of reminders to an array of their dates:
.animation(.spring, value: event.reminders.map(\.dateTime))


The map solution was perfect. Thanks a lot @Sweeper

It makes perfect sense and explains why I didn't find existing threads on this issue. However, do you still like the map solution for my specific use case? I'll update this comment as well according to your answer update.

@WorldNeedsRefactoring yeah I’d still use map. Perhaps “wrong” is too strong of a word. I just meant that I did not address the fact that changes in the array element order can be observed by SwiftUI, so it’s not entirely the issue of reference types. If you actually reorder event.reminders, SwiftUI will animate correctly.

It seems like I can't edit past comments; hence, this thread might be a bit confusing.
However, I explored further and added this to my example:
´´´
ForEach(event.reminders) { reminder in
ReminderView(reminder: reminder)
.background(reminder.dateTime.randomColorFromDate())
}
.animation(.spring(duration: 3), value: event.reminders)
´´´
The color change wasn't animated, even if I used the array directly(not sorted) @Sweeper

@WorldNeedsRefactoring well yeah. If you don’t reorder the array elements, SwiftUI cannot see change in dateTime. Whether you display it in a sorted way isn’t important. The key point is that event.reminders did not change (as in no reorder, insertion, or removal of elements). The elements’ properties changed, but SwiftUI cannot detect that, as I have explained.
